# Using DataDirectory in App.Config Connection String of a .Net Assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, assemblies, connection-string

My .edmx is included in another assembly. So the connection string configured in the App.Config file of the assembly.

I wanted to use |DataDirectory|dbfile.mdf in my connection string. But it doesn't work. It seems that DataDirectory cannot be resolved in the assembly.

The same connection string works from an MVC 3 web application.

Please let me know how can I use the DataDirectory in an assembly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An app.config for a library assembly is ignored at runtime. If it's a web app, set the connection string in the web.config. If it's an EXE, set the connection string in the app.config for the EXE, not the DLL which contains the EDMX.

Comment: Actually, I mainly require it when doing an "Update Model from Database" in the edmx view. It looks at App.Config. So there I don't want to hard code the path to the .mdf file as the project will compiled & used on different machines.

Comment: Right, Update Model uses app.config from the DLL. But that file will not be used at runtime. There's nothing "hard coded" about a .config file!

Comment: Mmm... when the same .config file is used on another machine, it should work as it is without changing the path of the db file. Hence the |DataDirectory| variable.